# How to set custom width of columns in right way?

Tags: css, grid-layout, postcss

I have a grid (I'm using "lost-grid") with two columns. One is 300px and the second one is 630px, container is 950px (20px is going to margin).
Here is the code:

```
.grid1{
  width: 100%;
  lost-center: 950px;
  lost-utility: clearfix;
}

.grid1__item{
  lost-column: 0.65895/2 0 2.11%;
}

.grid1__item_big{
  lost-column: 1.32632/2 0 0;
}
```

Is it ok to set width in this way: `(0.65895/2)`, or am I doing something wrong? If I set it in this way: `(1/2)`, I can't get the width that I need.

Comment: If your question really is "is it ok" you can just try running the code you've posted to get the answer.. otherwise you should tell us what exactly the problem is that you are having. Why do you need those particular fractions?

Comment: read up on css calc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

try to use this http://codepen.io/BackS/pen/OMBQKy

```
.grid1__item{
  lost-column: 300/950 0 0;
  margin-right: 20px !important;
}

.grid1__item_big{
  lost-column: 630/950 950 0;
}
```

Comment: this could work but its poor practice .... if youre using !important its time to stop and think where you went wrong upstream, or that maybe lost-columns arent what you want to be using for the situation